# RPM Packaging - No SOURCES files included in RPM

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have binary file that I would like place under `/etc/myapp/bin/app`

#### Here is my SPECS/app.spec file

```
%define _topdir     /root/rpmbuild
%define name        my-app
%define release     2
%define version     2.1
%define buildroot   %{_topdir}/%{name}-%{version}

Name:           %{name}
Summary:        Sample Application
License:        Private
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Group:          Applications/Tools
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
URL:            https://www.my-app.com
Source0:        %{_topdir}/SOURCES/%{name}-%{version}.tar.gz

%description
My App Desc

%prep
%setup -q

%build

%install
ls
cp etc/my-app/bin/app /etc/my-app/bin
cp etc/init.d/my-app /etc/init.d

chmod +x /etc/my-app/bin/app
chmod +x /etc/init.d/my-app


%files
%defattr(-,root,root)


%post
/etc/init.d/my-app start
/sbin/chkconfig --add /etc/my-app/bin/app


%preun
#last removal
service %{name} stop > /dev/null 2>&1
rm -rf /etc/my-app
rm -f /var/log/my-app
/sbin/chkconfig --del %{name}


%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%changelog
 # end mhash spec
```

#### And then I do

`rpmbuild -ba /root/rpmbuild/SPEC/app.spec`

#### This builds 3 files

`/root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/x86_64/my-app-2.1-2.src.rpm
/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/my-app-2.1-2.x86_64.rpm
/root/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/my-app-debuginfo-2.1-2.x86_64.rpm`

The size of the `.rpm` file is just 4kb where src package itself is 13MB.

#### What am I missing here? I have spent three days on this.. Any gelp will be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop building `debuginfo` packages, you need the following syntax at the top of your `spec` file,

```
  %define debug_package %{nil}
```

You have a couple of problems in the `spec` file. You are not using a `%{buildroot}` in your install section.

```
%install
# Create configuration directory for my-app
%{__mkdir_p} -m 0755 %{buildroot}/etc/my-app

# Use install that provides option for file permission
install -m 755 etc/my-app/bin %{buildroot}/etc/my-app/bin
install -m 644 etc/init.d/my-app %{buildroot}/etc/init.d/my-app
```

Make sure the package owns its files, otherwise you would get rpm build errors.

```
%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
%dir /etc/my-app
/etc/my-app/bin
/etc/init.d/my-app
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the same day the %files was empty. And what worked for me was `%undefine _missing_build_ids_terminate_build` to .spec file. Thanks to https://github.com/tpokorra/lbs-mono-fedora/issues/3

Comment: Good to know. The directories may not show in the check, so make sure you have the directory correctly owned by your pacakge.

Comment: Yes. I am setting up permissions for those files.